# Boot folder on external USB pendrive, how to boot to?

Tags: boot, grub2, usb, encryption, luks

My machine is LUKS-encrypted and boot works a charm (asking the passphrase at launch). I want to use a keyfile on a USB pendrive, thus the user has a dongle that the user must plug to launch Linux fully. I'm mainly inspired by this answer to do so: [LUKS encryption, header on a dongle USBdrive?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/654975/luks-encryption-header-on-a-dongle-usbdrive/654984?noredirect=1#comment946488_654984)

Well, I copied `/boot`and keyfile on the USB key, I have editted `/etc/crypptab`.

Now I want to make sure the machine will attempt to boot from the USB pendrive. I understand I have to edit `/etc/fstab`and I read the man and doc, but I'm totally lost.

The machine has /boot and / (FS). The USB has only /boot (+ keyfile inside, linked in `/etc/crypttab`).

> My question is: is it possible to tell my machine "try to boot from the pendrive [this is possible I know, but next:], if impossible: **fallback to the HDD** (and ask for the passphrase) ?  how ?

*NB: I'm affraid of doing wrong with fstab and my machine then does not boot anymore.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before doing anything that might make your system inoperable, [make a system back-up](https://askubuntu.com/a/581953/344926)!

You should be rightly afraid as "fallback to the hard drive" *is what you have right now, without making the USB stick!*

So what you're about to do by putting the ´/boot` on a USB stick, is making your system more secure and *with great security comes great responsibility, so the USB key getting lost, or getting stolen or just breaking **will make your system inaccessible!***

So before you go ahead:

1. Make [a system back-up](https://askubuntu.com/a/581953/344926)
2. Buy another USB key equal to or larger then the one you have.
3. Make an unencrypted data back-up and store it in a vault
4. Go back [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/654975/luks-encryption-header-on-a-dongle-usbdrive/654984?noredirect=1#comment946488_654984) and continue what you were doing
5. `dd` the contents of the first USB onto the second so you have a back-up of that.
6. Test both USB keys
7. Delete the unencrypted data back-up (or just [destroy the unencrypted back-up with a blowtorch](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4GXMoswMxRI)!)

### :-)

Comment: The answer is really interesting, but it does not say if **fallback** is possible (and potentially *how*) ;)